# autofac runtime-context based dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am working on a NopCommerce Plugin, an opensource project which uses autofac and asp.net mvc 5 .

Let's say I have the following types

1. an `IService` interface and two implementations `AService` and `BService`
2. an `IFactory` with a method `PrepareModel(Customer)` and an implementantion `Factory` with a dependency to `ISubFactory`
3. an `ISubFactory` and an implementantion `SubFactory` with a dependency to `IService`
4. a `Controller` which should depend on `IFactory`

Lastly, I have a setting for each `Customer` object indicating whether `AService` or `BService` should be used.

What I need is to resolve `IFactory` and its dependencies dependencies and call `Factory.PrepareModel(Customer)` from within actions of the `Controller`.

```
public ActionResult Foo(Customer customer)
{
    ...
    IFactory factory = //use AService if customer.aService else BService
    var model = factory.PrepareModel(customer)
    ...
}
```

Some thoughts :

1. I could pass around an instance of `IContainer`, however it is
   discouraged in the documentation of autofac.
2. I can't delegate `Factory` because I am handling interfaces
3. I could create an `IServiceFactory` with a method

   `IService GetService(Customer customer);`

   However, `ISubFactory` is not and should not be aware of the setting and thus the `IServiceFactory` can't be used.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you pass on `Customer` with the `PrepareModel`. This way you can create a proxy class for `IFactory` that can dispatch to another one of the `IFactory` implementations that it wraps. These factory instances could have their own object graph. One with `ServiceA`, the other with `ServiceB`.

Comment: @Steven I will experiment on that, I could create an `ISubFactoryFactory` with a dependency to `IIndex<string, ISubFactory>` and a method `ISubFactory GetFactory(Customer)` then call it inside `Factory.PrepareModel(Customer)`

Comment: Please don't create factories for factories. Read [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100). You should use a proxy instead. A proxy is different from a factory in that it encapsulates the factory behavior instead of leaking it out and complicating the consumer with it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to specify a Proxy that can forward the call to correct underlying implementation. Which level is the best to implement the Proxy depends on your design and application needs, but my guess is that you should specify a Proxy for `ISubFactory`.

The following code snippet shows a possible Proxy implementation for `ISubFactory`.

```
class DispatchingSubFactoryProxy : ISubFactory
{
    private readonly ISubFactory aFactory;
    private readonly ISubFactory bFactory;

    public DispatchingSubFactoryProxy(
        ISubFactory aFactory, ISubFactory bFactory)
    {
        this.aFactory = aFactory;
        this.bFactory = bFactory;
    }

    public Model PremareSubModel(Customer c) => GetFactory(c).PremareSubModel(c);
    ISubFactory GetFactory(Customer c) => c.aService ? aFactory : bFactory;
}
```

Using this `DispatchingSubFactoryProxy` you can create the following registrations to hook this up:

```
container.RegisterType<ServiceA>().AsSelf();
container.RegisterType<ServiceB>().AsSelf();

container.Register<ISubFactory>(c =>
    new DispatchingSubFactoryProxy(
        aFactory: new SubFactory(c.Resolve<ServiceA>())
        bFactory: new SubFactory(c.Resolve<ServiceB>())));
```